# Get Rid Of Huge Table Titles in concated htmlTable [R]

Tags: html, r, html-table

How can I get rid of the huge table titles in htmlTable in R? (in my example I want to get rid of "Table no. 1" and "Table no. 2")

Create example data:

```
data1 <- data.frame(data1="example_data",data1col1="example_data",data1col2=5,stringsAsFactors = F)

data2 <- data.frame(data2="example_data",data2col1="example_data",data2col2="text_data",data2col3=5, data2col4="more_stuff_here",stringsAsFactors = F)
```

Stack tables and create html:

```
library(htmlTable)  
y1 <- htmlTable(data1, rnames = FALSE,caption="DATA 1")
y2 <- htmlTable(data2, rnames = FALSE, caption="DATA 2")
y <- concatHtmlTables(list(y1,y2))
```

Currently creates this with the huge titles I want to get rid of:

[image]

How can I create the same stacked tables without the huge table titles?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can pass empty `headers`.

```
library(htmlTable)  

y <- concatHtmlTables(list(y1,y2), headers = '')
y
```

[image]

Comment: I knew there had to be a simple answer. Thanks!